# Test for Convergence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{7^{3n}}{n!}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{\ln\frac{n+5}{n+2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Test the following series for convergence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{7^{3n}}{n!}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{\ln\frac{n+5}{n+2}}$$

I need this for studying purposes, I have an exam next week and I am struggling to work on them. Can anyone assist?

I tried using the ratio test, am I on the right track?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Welcome. Posting image is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Since you are new contributor, the images have been converted to text for once (If you can't see text, assume that conversion process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. If possible, we would like to see your efforts on question too. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 3):

For first question, use ratio test. For second question, notice that when $n$ is large, $\frac{n + 5}{n + 2} < e$ so $\log\frac{n + 5}{n + 2} < 1$. Now, if you take square root of a number less than one, you get a larger number. That is,

$$
0 \leq x \leq 1 \implies \sqrt{x} \geq x
$$

Therefore for $n$ large enough, let's say $n \geq 100$,

$$
\sum_{n=100}^{\infty} \sqrt{\log\frac{n + 5}{n + 2}} \geq \sum_{n=100}^{\infty} \log\frac{n + 5}{n + 2} = \log\left(\prod_{n=100}^{\infty} \frac{n + 5}{n + 2}\right) = \infty
$$

Since the product is telescoping.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should ask the question better.
Try using D'Alembert's test, you should know it because it's very useful.
Let $$a_{n}=\frac{7^{3n}}{n!},$$ so $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{7^3}{n+1},$$ which obviusly goes to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. So the quotient converges to a value less than $1$, so the series converges.